# RedHat: Can't install package GNOME Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, gnome

I installed the package GNOME Desktop Environment on my machine running Red Hat version 6.4.

```
more /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

At the end of the installation I got an error about missing **RPM-  GPG-KEY-oracle** directory.

```
    [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-  GPG-KEY-oracle
```

How can I resolve this problem?

```
[root@MY_BABY ~]#  yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
ol6_UEK_latest                    | 1.2 kB     00:00
ol6_latest                        | 1.4 kB     00:00
rhel-6-server-rpms                | 3.7 kB     00:00
rhel-6-server-rpms/primary_db     |  30 MB     00:07   

.
.
.
.
.
.


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------------

                                                                                           1.8 MB/s |  34 MB     00:18     
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle


GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-  GPG-KEY-oracle
```

I also tried this

```
wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el5
--2015-01-05 13:28:14--  http://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el5
Resolving public-yum.oracle.com... 82.166.201.211
Connecting to public-yum.oracle.com|82.166.201.211|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1397 (1.4K) [text/plain]
Saving to: âRPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el5.1â 0s  


rpm --import ./RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el5
```

but still do not have the directory under `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/`.

```
ls /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-  GPG-KEY-oracle
```

This is what I have in `/etc/yum.repos.d`:

```
# ls /etc/yum.repos.d
mirrors-rpmforge          public-yum-ol6.repo  rpmforge.repo             swp-default-    LVS-repo.repo
mirrors-rpmforge-extras   redhat.repo          service-cd-LVS-repo.repo  swp-default-    repo.repo
mirrors-rpmforge-testing  rhel-source.repo     service-cd-repo.repo      swp-vmware-    tools-repo.repo
```

Comment: Why are there Oracle Linux repositories on this system?

Comment: hi Michael , we are using this linux red-hat machine for along time , so I am not know the answer for your question but what we need is to install the Desktop GUI on our linux machine

Comment: but if yum insist the RPM- GPG-KEY-oracle directory , then how we can create this directory with there contents ?

Answer (score 1):

This may actually be OEL 6, not RHEL 6. However, the solution is close to what you attempted - you simply need to obtain the OEL 6 RPM-GPG-KEY file from Oracle, not the OEL 5 key. I haven't tried this myself as I don't have OEL systems, but I think you can do this with `wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el6`, then `rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el6`. If those exact commands don't work, very similar ones should. Then you should be able to install packages normally; you should not need the file in `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/` once the `rpm --import` completes successfully.

Alternately, if this is RHEL 6 and you don't want the OEL repositories / packages, simply remove any OEL defeinitions in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory tree (and any packages that own the OEL files), or otherwise disable the OEL repos, and reissue the original `yum` command. You should then pull the correct RHEL GNOME packages.

Comment: Hi John - this is absolutly red-hat machine ( see the update in my question (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server)

Comment: John , how to disable the OEL ? by command ? and how to reissue the original RPM - can you please give example for that?

Comment: The solution remains the same, then - remove or disable the unwanted OEL repositories and re-run the `yum install` command. You have a number of extra repositories defined on this machine that I'm not sure you want, I would audit it carefully.

Comment: about what you said "unwanted OEL repositories" you mean that I need to remove all the files that ended with .repo under  /etc/yum.repos.d directory ??

Comment: as ls /etc/yum.repos.d | grep ".repo"
public-yum-ol6.repo
redhat.repo
rhel-source.repo
rpmforge.repo
service-cd-LVS-repo.repo
service-cd-repo.repo
swp-default-LVS-repo.repo
swp-default-repo.repo
swp-vmware-tools-repo.repo

Comment: Not all files that end in `.repo` define OEL repositories.

Comment: so how to delete only the files that define OEL repositories?

Comment: or maybe the second option - disable the OEL repos ( but how to disable ? )

Comment: by the way when I do rpm -qa | grep -i oel , then I dont get any rpm packages ,